# Finite-Type Algebra Property Under Change of Base

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

I was wondering how to prove the following assertion. Any help would be appreciated!

Suppose we have to ring homomorphisms: $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: B \rightarrow C$.

Then $C$ being finite type over $A$ implies that $C$ is finite type over $B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$C$ being finite type over $A$ means that any element of $c\in C$ is of the form
$$ c=\sum_{i=1}^ka_ix_i^{\alpha_i}$$
for $x_1,\ldots, x_k$ a fixed set of generators in $C$ and $a_i\in A$. Note that this above expression really means
$$ c=\sum_{i=1}^k (g\circ f)(a_i)x_i^{\alpha_i}$$
by the definition of the algebra structure. In particular, if we set $f(a_i)=b_i$, we have
$$ c=\sum_{i=1}^k g(b_i)x_i^{\alpha_i}$$
for $b_i\in B$. This is the same thing as $C$ being finite type over $B$ with generators $x_1,\ldots,x_k$: e.g.
$$ c=\sum_{i=1}^k b_ix_i^{\alpha_i}.$$

Comment: I wasn' aware of the fact that $a_i$ actually means $(f \circ g)(a_i)$, since our lecture notes and the people online discussing this topic don't say that. Do you know why none of the sources I used say this? Could it be interpreted in a different way?

Comment: When you have an algebra structure $f:A\to B$ on $B$ as an $A-$algebra, then the _definition_ of $a\cdot b$ is $f(a)\cdot b$. Actually, if you think about it there is no other way, since $A$ is not a subset of $B$ a priori.